# How to show background image in list view via parsing json data with use of volley while image is not loaded

Tags: android, json, image, listview, android-volley

How to show background image in list view via parsing json data with use of volley while image is not loaded .or if image url is not present in json then by default background image should be appear.

in the image you can see in the list ist image url is not present in json so ist image is appearing as a blank image      .[image]

While it should be appear as a default image.

I have to replace blank image with one image. and i want to place one background image while the image is not loading it should be appear as default for all image . Once the image will be download then image should be replace with default image
I have used Volley Library .
How can i set background image with when image is not loaded and where image url is not present it should be come as a background image by default ?

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String url = "http://lztsyhmtyk.localtunnel.me/api/v1/restaurants?per_page=10&page=1&sort_col=average_ratings";
    // Movies json url
    //private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image_url"));
                                movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                                movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                                movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                                //movie.setAddress(obj.getString("address"));
                                //movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));
                                // Genre is json array
                                /*JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/
                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

listrow.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bc"
            />
        <!-- Restaurant name  -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/area"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <!-- Rating -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/average_ratings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/area"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"

            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cuisine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/average_ratings"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <!-- Genre -->
       <!-- <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rating"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textColor="@color/genre"
            android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />-->
    <!--
        &lt;!&ndash; Release Year &ndash;&gt;
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/year"
            android:textSize="@dimen/year" />-->

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Movie.java

```
public class Movie {
    private String name, thumbnailUrl;
    //private int year;
    private String average_ratings,area,cuisine,address;
//  private ArrayList<String> genre;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String name, String thumbnailUrl, String average_ratings,String area,String cuisine,String address
            ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        //this.year = year;
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
        this.area=area;
        this.cuisine=cuisine;
this.address=address;
        //this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    /*public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }*/

    /*public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }*/

    public String getAverage_ratings() {
        return average_ratings;
    }

    public void setAverage_ratings(String average_ratings) {
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCuisine() {
        return cuisine;
    }

    public void setCuisine(String cuisine) {
        this.cuisine = cuisine;
    }
    /*public ArrayList<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(ArrayList<String> genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
*/
}
```

customlistadapter.java

```
 public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<Movie> movieItems;
        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.movieItems = movieItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return movieItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return movieItems.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            if (imageLoader == null)
                imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            /*ImageView img;
            img = (ImageView)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img);

            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);
            else {*/
            NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView average_ratings = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.average_ratings);
            TextView address=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area);
            TextView cuisine =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cuisine);
            //TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            //TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

            // getting movie data for the row
            Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

            // thumbnail image
            //thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
            //if (TextUtils.isEmpty(m.getThumbnailUrl()))
                //thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);



            //else
                //Log.d("KeyHash:","Neeraj");
                thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
            /*if (m.getThumbnailUrl().compareTo("")!=0)
                thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
            //else{
            //thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);

                else {

                    thumbNail.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
                    //thumbNail.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.bc);

            }*/


            // title
            name.setText(m.getName());

            // rating
            average_ratings.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getAverage_ratings()));
            address.setText("Area: " + String.valueOf(m.getAddress()));
            cuisine.setText("Cusine: " + String.valueOf(m.getCuisine()));
            /*// genre
            String genreStr = "";
            for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
                genreStr += str + ", ";
            }
            genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                    genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
            genre.setText(genreStr);

            // release year
            year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));*/

            return convertView;
        }



    }
```

App controller.java

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
```

[image: After change it is appearing as]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your adapter after removing your another imageview

```
 // get reference of your imageloader 
   imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();  

    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        thumbNail .setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.yourdrawable);

       // getting movie data for the row
            Movie m = movieItems.get(position); 

// now it time to load image 
 thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer . Now where image url is present . It is coming with background image . both are merging . both are appearing . First background image is appearing then image url is also coming . it should be replace background image. But it is not happening why?   see in the 2nd image. what i have attached . it is coming as a both image are appearing .

Comment: by doing this . both image are coming .what is the solution for same . see in the 2nd image . both image are appearing .

Comment: just remove your imageview , and use this method to load image to replace default background with image loaded from your passed url (IMAGE_URL) mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);

Comment: i have removed image view but where i have to add mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader);

Comment: Thanks for your effort . I  have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your ImageView and set `android:src="@drawable/bc"` to your NetworkImageView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bc" />
        <!-- Restaurant name  -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/area"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <!-- Rating -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/average_ratings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/area"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"

            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cuisine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/average_ratings"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

        <!-- Genre -->
       <!-- <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genre"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rating"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:textColor="@color/genre"
            android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />-->
    <!--
        &lt;!&ndash; Release Year &ndash;&gt;
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="@color/year"
            android:textSize="@dimen/year" />-->

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i did but image is appeared but background image is appearing with image url . When image url is present then both image are appearing . whrn image url is not present then background image is appearing which i want . But one problem is that background image is appearing with image url image it is problem . see the second image .

Comment: i did same but when i am scrolling down and going up again background image is not appearing where image url is not present . there should be present background image where image url is not present. First time it is appearing but going up and down in list it disappearing . why ?

Answer (score 0):

Changes in CustomListAdapter & list_row.xml required.

Update :

CustomListAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        /*ImageView img;
        img = (ImageView)convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img);

        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);
        else {*/

        NetworkImageView _ImageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
         _ImageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
        //NetworkImageView.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), ImageLoader);
        /*NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);*/
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView average_ratings = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.average_ratings);
        TextView address=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.area);
        TextView cuisine =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cuisine);
        //TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        //TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        //_ImageView.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        /*if (TextUtils.isEmpty(m.getThumbnailUrl()))
            thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);



        else
            //Log.d("KeyHash:","Neeraj");*/
        _ImageView.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        /*if (m.getThumbnailUrl().compareTo("")!=0)
            thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        //else{
        //thumbNail.setImageResource(R.drawable.bc);

            else {

                thumbNail.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.bc);
                //thumbNail.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.bc);

        }*/


        // title
        name.setText(m.getName());

        // rating
        average_ratings.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getAverage_ratings()));
        address.setText("Area: " + String.valueOf(m.getAddress()));
        cuisine.setText("Cusine: " + String.valueOf(m.getCuisine()));
        /*// genre
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        // release year
        year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));*/

        return convertView;
    }



}
```

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        />

    <!-- Restaurant name  -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/area"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Rating -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/average_ratings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/area"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"

        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cuisine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/average_ratings"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

    <!-- Genre -->
   <!-- <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rating"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre" />-->
<!--
    &lt;!&ndash; Release Year &ndash;&gt;
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year" />-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

see in the images after changes problem is solved .
[image]